# Disabling scientific notation on a scale matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale

I'm trying to make a graph with non-scientific notation on y-scale. My code looks like this:

```
fig = mpl.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.semilogy(x,(y-0.9*best_vals[0]),'--',color = 'gray', lw = 1,fillstyle = 'none', label = 'experiment')
ax.semilogy(x[start:],(y_fit-0.9*best_vals[0]),'r-', label = '4-exponential fit')

ax.set_xlim(0,5000)
ax.set_ylim(1e2,1e6)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
```

If the upper limit of y scale is set up to 1e5 it look perfectly fine with y ticks 100, 1000, 10000, 100000. But when I try to make it 1e6 y notation changes to scientific with upper limit 0.1e7. Is there any chance to force it to be 1000000 rather than 0.1e7? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable scientific notation with

```
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```